# how to add another paired column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l','b-a', 'd-c', 'f-e', 'h-g', 'j-i', 'l-k']})
```

You have one column that has a combination overlapped despite the fact that the order seems reversed. But how to add another column on the other side to actually show that they are the same like the below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l','b-a', 'd-c', 'f-e', 'h-g', 'j-i', 'l-k']
,'col2':['a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l','a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l']})
```

The real data is not predictable as the sequence of alpha beta, so I got a headache.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions. I think it is the beauty of Python to have all different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby(df.col1.str.split('-').map(lambda x : tuple(sorted(x)))).col1.transform('first')
0     a-b
1     c-d
2     e-f
3     g-h
4     i-j
5     k-l
6     a-b
7     c-d
8     e-f
9     g-h
10    i-j
11    k-l
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

**`map`** with **`ord`**  and get `sum` of each row , followed by **`groupby()+transform('first')`**:

```
f = df['col1'].str.split('-').explode().map(ord).sum(level=0)
df.assign(col2=df.groupby(f).transform('first'))
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0   a-b  a-b
1   c-d  c-d
2   e-f  e-f
3   g-h  g-h
4   i-j  i-j
5   k-l  k-l
6   b-a  a-b
7   d-c  c-d
8   f-e  e-f
9   h-g  g-h
10  j-i  i-j
11  l-k  k-l
```

Comment: sorry not working... the real data is not only one character

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l','b-a', 'd-c', 'f-e', 'h-g', 'j-i', 'l-k']})
def order(x):
    return x if x[0]<x[-1] else ''.join(x[::-1])
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(order)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0   a-b  a-b
1   c-d  c-d
2   e-f  e-f
3   g-h  g-h
4   i-j  i-j
5   k-l  k-l
6   b-a  a-b
7   d-c  c-d
8   f-e  e-f
9   h-g  g-h
10  j-i  i-j
11  l-k  k-l
```

I created function which simply compares first and last character (give same result as comparing their ASCII codes) and depending on outcome `return`s what was feed or reversed `str`. Then I use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) which is useful when you need to apply function (or other transform) to elements of column of dataframe. This solution assumes all your data is correct i.e. always is consisting of:

- single lowercase letter
- single `-`
- single lowercase letter

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.split('-'
,expand=True).stack().sort_values().groupby(level=0).agg('-'.join)


print(df)

   col1 col2
0   a-b  a-b
1   c-d  c-d
2   e-f  e-f
3   g-h  g-h
4   i-j  i-j
5   k-l  k-l
6   b-a  a-b
7   d-c  c-d
8   f-e  e-f
9   h-g  g-h
10  j-i  i-j
11  l-k  k-l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def transformer(value):
   alphabets=value.split('-')
   return value if ord(alphabets[0])<ord(alphabets[1]) else alphabets[1]+'-'+alphabets[0]
df['col2']= df['col1'].transform(transformer)
```

Explanation: Using transform() for df['col1'], I am applying the function transformer() defined above where I split the string & check if the ASCII value of 1st alphabet is lesser than 2nd alphabet & returning the result accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This builds off @anky's solution, using [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) :

```
df['flip'] = [ent
              if ord(ent[0]) < ord(ent[-1])
              else ent[-1]+'-'+ent[0]
              for ent in df.col1.array]

   col1 flip
0   a-b a-b
1   c-d c-d
2   e-f e-f
3   g-h g-h
4   i-j i-j
5   k-l k-l
6   b-a a-b
7   d-c c-d
8   f-e e-f
9   h-g g-h
10  j-i i-j
11  l-k k-l
```

Answer (score -1):

It is somewhat hard to tell what you are asking from the original post. Are you asking about duplicating a column?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a-b', 'c-d', 'e-f', 'g-h', 'i-j', 'k-l','b-a', 'd-c', 'f- 
e', 'h-g', 'j-i', 'l-k']})

df['col2'] = df['col1']
```

Comment: you totally missed the mark on the question, he wanted to sort the values to see the duplicates.